# how to use node http proxy for redirecting only one page through proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, proxy

This is the first time that I am using node http proxy.
I want to use node http proxy on onClick event of a link, which should redirect to a particular page.

here is a link:
    Help

getFromProxy function redirects the help page via proxy.

```
function getFromProxy() {
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://google.co.in' });
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

It redirects to nginx welcome message. I don't want to use nginx. I tried to find a solution but could not find it. Please guide me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I use node-http-proxy this way? Is this a right way to use it?